# Starting Apache2 on Ubuntu Failed

Tags: apache2

I used the the Ubuntu with and MYSQL installation guide for OSQA. It was very simple to follow until I reached the last step, which was starting the Apache2 server. I double checked to see if I missed any of the previous steps and I did happen to miss one. It was the sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/osqa /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/osqa command. So I ran this command from my root directory. After running the above command I tried starting the Apache2 server again. It still didn't work. I then ran these commands:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /home/osqa/osqa-server/forum/upfiles
sudo chmod -R g+w /home/osqa/osqa-server/log
```

These didn't help with the issue. The errors I get when I start or restart the server are:

```
osqa@osqa-Latitude-E4300:/$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[sudo] password for osqa: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for osqa: 
apache2: Syntax error on line 230 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/osqa: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/osqa:7: <VirtualHost> was not closed.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

The installation guide I was following was:http://wiki.osqa.net/display/docs/Ubuntu+with+Apache+and+MySQL

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Comment: It tells you about the problem! `<VirtualHost> was not closed` - there is no `</VirtualHost>` tag in config file.

Answer (score 5):

the configuration file of your server has errors. Open `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` with a text editor and add a VirtualHost closing tag: `</VirtualHost>`

Comment: So just add VirtualHost to the end of apache2.conf?

Comment: not necessary at the end of the file, you may have other virtualhosts defined, close the one that has no </VirtualHost> and is before any other opening tags <>. Your log says is at line 7

Answer (score 1):

End the virtualhost tag:

`</VirtualHost>`
(it's located after line **7**)

Answer (score 0):

That depends if your running more then one virtualhost you must close each virtualhost before starting another one

```
<VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/host.example.com
    ServerName host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/host.example.com-error_log
    TransferLog logs/host.example.com-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had some ssl certs wrong. Make sure your cert and private key are valid and match!