# Unable to start Apache on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

After years of giving no trouble, my connection to localhost has stopped working. When I enter:-

```
http://localhost/phpinfo.php
```

the error message

> This webpage is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

is returned. I then attempt to restart apache, thus:-

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This produces the following error message:-

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
         Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/log_sql.load:
         Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_sql.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_sql.so: 
          undefined symbol: ap_log_error_
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

The line of apache2.conf causing the issue is here:-

```
Include mods-enabled/*.load
```

and in log_sql.load:-

```
LoadModule log_sql_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_sql.so
```

The file mod_log_sql.so exists.

I have check the error log and it doesn't contain anything (i.e. has no bytes in it). Does anyone know what the matter is, and how I can fix it?

The apache configuration is a LAMP stack straight out of the tin. I haven't (to the best of my knowledge) done anything to even tweak it, and it has been going nicely for some years.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318983/starting-apache2-on-ubuntu-failed) question is related but has a different error message. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537226/apache-2-error-after-performing-update-on-ubuntu-server) fellow here appears to have a related problem.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: the module `mod_log_sql.so` has been compiled for a different version of Apache, so it can't be loaded.

Are any of `mod_log_sql.so` or Apache installed manually (i.e., not from the Ubuntu repository)? You can search if `mod_log_sql.so` has been installed from a package using:

```
dpkg -S /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_sql.so
```

It is not clear why this has to be a "syntax error" though...

Comment: didn't see "he apache configuration is a LAMP stack straight out of the tin". Try to update the packages - maybe it was a bug in the original distribution

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The result of your suggested command is `libapache2-mod-log-sql: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_sql.so`. I don't pretend to understand what that means. Do you suggest a re-install?